# Ember js wait for controller this.get request / rest adapter lag

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to access my model's content in its respective controller but it initially returns a promise with undefined attributes, then when accessed a second or third time it returns the value.

Could it be there is a delay in retrieving data from the REST adapter?

Also trying to use '.then()' on the request in a controller does not work as I believe it for use only in the route.

```
App.EquipmentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    getContentForMapping: function() {
        console.log(this.get('model').objectAt(1).get('contractor.name'));
        //returns undefined first time 
    }
});
```

What is strange is that when I access the model's properties from the template view in a loop it returns them straight away.

```
{{#each equipment in model}}
   <p>{{equipment.contractor.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Below is how I have set up the route. It's grabbing a list of equipment relevant to a specific site:

```
App.EquipmentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      //Get the model for the selected site and grab its equipment list.  
      return this.modelFor('site').get('equipment'); 
  },
  //Set the model we just grabbed above as the model to use in the controller
  setupController: function(controller, model) { 
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need setupController. That's the default implementation. 
setupController: function(controller, model) { 
    controller.set('model', model);
  }

Comment: How're you calling getContentForMapping? It seems like it might be a timing issue and you're calling that function before the promise is resolved. The template will wait until the promise is resolved in order to render the each. Could you send a jsbin reproducing the issue?

Comment: Hey Miguel, getContentForMapping is called via updating a field. I tried to reproduce it with a jsbin using a fixure adapter but the problem did not seem to replicate which leaves me to believe its REST adapter related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing our API endpoint to support sideloading seems to have fixed the delay we were experiencing when making the `this.get('model')` request.

There is a small section in the ember guides that covers this: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

Comment: I would still love to know how to make a `this.get()` request with some kind of callback or promise handling in a controller

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is in your `App.EquipmentsRoute`'s `setupController` function. Try to set the `content` property, not the model hook property.

```
controller.set('content', model);
```

in

```
App.EquipmentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  [...] 
  setupController: function(controller, model) { 
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey splattne thanks for the answer but it does not seem to fix my problem :(